# Migration is not running after creating SQL database in C#

Tags: c#, database-migration

I managed to create the following unit test base class so as each test class have separate database.

```
public class BaseTestClass
{
    public HttpClient _httpClient;
    internal Context context { get; set; }

    protected BaseTestClass()
    {
        var webApplicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
              .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<Context>>();
                services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            });
        });

        var scope = webApplicationFactory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()!.CreateScope();
        context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        context.Database.Migrate();

        _httpClient = webApplicationFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Dispose();
    }
```

The database is created but the tables are missing. The migrations are the main project (Program.cs) How could I say the context to use MIgrations from the main project?

Comment: Migration creates a mapping between the c# classes/properties and the database tables/fields.  Migration has two modes 1) Create 2) Update.  Make sure if you are modifying the properties that you use Update.  Are your properties public?